# XmlSerializer produces different output for x86 and x64

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, namespaces

I have the following sample code that produces a different output for x86 and x64.

```
class SampleSerializer
{
   public static string Serialize(string[] samples)
   {
      var xmlDocument = string.Empty;

      var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
         xmlSerializer.Serialize(
            ms,
            samples);

         xmlDocument = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      }

      return xmlDocument;
   }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var samples = new string[] { };

      var doc = SampleSerializer.Serialize(samples);

      Console.WriteLine(doc);
   }
}
```

When the platform target is x86 the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

When the platform target is x64 the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

You can achieve the same with Any CPU and Prefer 32-bit set or unset.

If you look carefully, the order of the namespaces, `xsi` and `xsd`, is different. Why is it so? I would expect the order of the namespaces to be platform independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` internally uses `Hashtable` to keep namespaces ([this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs#L117), then [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializerNamespaces.cs#L65)), so you can simplify your sample to the following:

```
var hash = new Hashtable();
hash.Add("xsi", null);
hash.Add("xsd", null);

foreach (var name in hash.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

x86:

```
xsi
xsd
```

x64:

```
xsd
xsi
```

Reproduced! Technically that's expected, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The order of the keys in the ICollection is unspecified

If that is not enough, we can start walking on thin ice here and guess *why it is so*. My best guess here is that order of Keys depends on Keys' hash codes.

Ok, let's try:

```
Console.WriteLine("xsi: {0:x8}", "xsi".GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("xsd: {0:x8}", "xsd".GetHashCode());
```

x86:

```
xsi: c5864a25
xsd: c2b84cce
```

x64:

```
xsi: b9b66082
xsd: b9b66087
```

Same strings, different hash codes for different platforms!

But again that's expected per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain.

Ho ho ho, "they can even differ by application domain"!

Now I would not rely on `XmlSerializer` always produce stable results..

Comment: That makes sense.